# Construction of an AND Gate from NOR Gates

Tags: python, logic, boolean-algebra, nor

One of the alternate to getting the same output as an AND Gate, is to put together NOR gates. The operator for NOT gates is `(A+B)'`, However there is a problem, I can't get the same output an AND gate would.

This [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysTsl.png) is from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOR_logic

So for example if we take:

`A = 1` `B = 0`, I would expect 0 as a result, but that does not seem to be the case here since,

```
= (1 NOR 0) NOR (1 NOR 0)
= (0) NOR (0)
= 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is indeed an error in your expression.

The key here is to see that the first two ports each take a pair of values that are duplicates. So we have

```
(A NOR A)
(B NOR B)
```

[image]

This evaluates a NOT operation, so we get:

```
(NOT A)
(NOT B)
```

These two are then the operands of the final NOR, giving the desired result.

For your example with `A = 1` `B = 0`:

```
(1 NOR 1) == 0
(0 NOR 0) == 1
```

And

```
0 NOR 1 == 0
```

#### All possibilities

| A | B | A NOR A | B NOR B | (A NOR A) NOR (B NOR B) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: Oh my bad, thank you :)